# ¿Porque visual studio code no subraya los errores de sintaxis en el codigo?

Tags: vscode

Hace poco instale visual studio code y lo configure con python el punto es que cuando cometo un error
de sintaxis este no me subraya el error para yo saberlo.

[image: error]

como ven escribi todo eso mal a proposito y nada.

Comment: Verifica que tienes instalado/habilitado el *linter* específico para Python en VSCode. Más info en la [documentación](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting). Saludos

Comment: Perdona, tengo el mismo problema que tu, ¿encontraste alguna solución?

Comment: @Cuzu debes instalar una extension para eso.

Answer (score 1):

Me ha pasado algo parecido trabajando en C. Dudo que esta sea la forma mas correcta de solucionar el problema pero a mi me ha servido.

Si haces clic derecho en el texto (o Control + shift + p) se te abrirá una especie de navegador. En él escribe "Habilitar el subrayado ondulado de errores" y selecciona esa opción.

Espero haber ayudado :)

Answer (score 0):

VSC Es prácticamente un editor de texto que quiere decir esto, que no detecta un lenguaje como tal por si solo, por esto es que no detecta el error. La solucion es instalar extensiones del lenguaje que quieras usar para que detecte errores y la sintaxis del lenguaje